# Send an image with hyperlink via email Java

Tags: java, image, email, hyperlink

Is there a possibility to send an image with hyperlink via email in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this through the library javamail.

Then you'll have to use html (a markup language) which supports hyperlinks.

[Here's](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm) an example to use html & javamail

Comment: Actually I thought that I already tried it but it didn't work, now I just noticed that my Apple's Mail provider wont show me the images but Gmail does..

So this is the code (for example):
message.setContent("<p>Create a link of an image:<a href=\"http://www.w3schools.com\"><img src=\"http://www.rgagnon.com/images/jht.gif\">","text/html" );

But I would like to send a image from my HD, and if I do so instead of an image I see just a question mark with a hyperlink.. it won't upload my image from my HD? is there a nice solution to that?