# How to convert a big URL to a small text while sending email

Tags: java, email, jakarta-ee, gmail-api

I am using below API which is working fine:

```
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);    
StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();    
String purchaseHistoryUrl ="someURL";    
body.append( "<a href='" + purchaseHistoryUrl + "'>here</a>");    
message.setContent(body.toString(), "text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

I have a big URL:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/#inbox?compose=15728437dfc5f1f5
```

and I want to make this big URL as 
something as "Please click here" as hyperlink in email.

Comment: you are sending "someUrl" without creating any html tag, thus it will just display the entire URL. Take a look at the [anchor tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) and replace the `someUrl` with `<a href='someUrl'>Please click here</a>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send an image with hyperlink via email Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243265/send-an-image-with-hyperlink-via-email-java)

Comment: Thanks [Shahid](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3399105/shahid). You edited the question to put the right answer in place of the question. Now the question is incoherent.

Comment: thanks dubes its working

Answer (score -1):

`body.append("<a href='" + purchaseHistoryUrl + "'>Here</a>")`

Not very good to use concatanation in StringBuilder but it's for clarity